# Store api responce without get method in pyspark

Tags: python, api, pyspark, azure-functions

We have deployed API in azure function API having only "post" method there is no "get" method, so here am getting below error to store the data:

Am able to see required data in print command but am unable to save, so please help me how can i save the api response in this code it self.

Code:

```
a = 0
while a<len(Loan_number):
    Loan = [Loan_number[a]]
    loanid = ' '.join(map(str,Loan))
    loan_id = loan_detail_df.filter(col("Loan_Number").isin(loanid))
    loan = loan_id.toPandas()
    loan_df = loan.to_dict(orient='records')
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print("Application Started")
    
        rest_api_url ="<API Path>"
        input_data = loan_df
    
        headers = {'content-type' : 'application/json'}
        rest_api_responce_data = requests.post(url=rest_api_url, data = json.dumps(input_data), headers = headers)

        response = requests.get(rest_api_url)
        response_df = response

        print(rest_api_responce_data)
        print(rest_api_responce_data.content)

   a+=1
```

Thank you

Comment: All requests have a response no matter what verb (GET, POST, etc.) you use although in some cases the response body is empty. So the fact the API you use doesn't allow a GET method doesn't matter. It sounds like you are getting an error with your current code. You will have to show it to us, or better yet, create a small example that causes the same error, in order for us to help.

Comment: abc = rest_api_responce_data.content this is the first step am doing then this abc dataframe am trying to convert as table, so am getting below error:AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'withColumn'

Comment: Help me how to store api response as json which API dont have get method

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code instead of posting a comment. Be sure to post enough code that we can actually run it ourselves. See [mcve] for more tips on creating a good code example.

Comment: i have updated my question with code, thank you

Comment: What is the output of `print(rest_api_responce_data.content)`? Most likely you can write this to a file or save it to a database instead of printing it to the console.

Comment: this command help to see the content of data, am unable to convert it it dataframe, if i do then only we can save it as json file, am looking to save the response in json format

Comment: Without more details, I can only make a guess. Please [edit] your question to show some example output.